# Please could hats be ordered by when they were earned?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, winter-bash-2015, winter-bash

Like several others, I've been keeping an eye on the [leaderboards](http://winterbash2015.stackexchange.com/leaderboard) for [Winter Bash 2015](http://winterbash2015.stackexchange.com). One thing I've found annoying is that when people gain a new hat and change position, it's not always clear *which* hat they've just earned. I can tell their total number of hats has changed, but no more than that, unless I happen to remember exactly which hats they'd already earned before.

It would be much easier to follow the leaderboards if **each user's hats were shown in the order they've been earned**. Then, for instance, this screenshot

[image]

would tell me that Bhargav Rao's hat count on SO had gone up from 26 to 27 because they'd just earned the Living in the Future hat there, rather than having to guess which hat they'd earned most recently.

In particular, this would make it easier to **spot new secret hats** for those who haven't earned them yet: just go to the network leaderboard and check the top hatters' most recent hats to see whether any unknown ones have appeared.

<sub>(I realise it's probably too late to implement this for the 2015 Winter Bash, but maybe something to consider for next year?)</sub>

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> In particular, this would make it easier to **spot new secret hats** for those who haven't earned them yet

– that also strikes me as the *only* reason why that sort order would be interesting.

But a user's leaderboard entry isn't there to help *you* find new hats, it's there for *them* to show the awesomeness that is their hat rack.

And that's why those hats are and will remain ordered by awesomeness, or rather, the closest proxy we have for that: rarity.

Comment: I didn't realise they're currently ordered by rarity. That also makes sense - thanks.

Comment: Also, if they are ordered by rarity, a new secret hat would probably be one of the 9 rarest hats earned by a person.